# javascript confirm(cancel) still submits form when using return false?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

i am using the following code:

```
        <form method='POST' action='post.php' style='margin-bottom:0px;'>
        <input type='image' name='close_x' src='imgs/button.png' onclick='confirmClose()'>
        </form>

       function confirmClose() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to close?')) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

however, when you click cancel in the confirm box, it still submits the form.

Surely the return false should stop this from happening?

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: onclick='return confirmClose()'

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inline event handlers.

```js
document.getElementsByName('close_x')[0].onclick = function confirmClose(e) {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you wish to close?'))
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

```css
#myform {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform" method='POST' action='post.php'>
  <input type='image' name='close_x' src='imgs/button.png'>
</form>
```