# Cancel confirm windows but

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, confirm

When I click cancel the form submit((
Why? 
I tried add to "". Everything is okey. But I need confirmation only when tr backgorund color is yellow. This way it doesn't cancel sumbmition...

```
$('#cart_form').submit(function() {
    $("tr").each(function(indx, element)
    {

        if (element.style.backgroundColor=="rgb(255, 255, 179)"){
            var c = confirm("Are u sure?");
            return c;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393860/javascript-confirmcancel-still-submits-form-when-using-return-false?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `return`ing from the function you pass to `each()`. See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) which says:

> You can stop **the loop** from within the callback function by returning false.

The **loop**, not the form submission!

---

You need to return from the function you pass to `submit()` (or, better, capture the first argument given to that function ([the event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)) and [call `preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on it).

Comment: Ok, I've understood.But how should I change the code? )) Sorry.

Comment: I described how to change the code in the answer. I linked to an example in the documentation.